# (Python) Function decorator to pass Playwright Page object to wrapped function

Tags: python, python-3.x, decorator, wrapper, python-decorators

**Goal**: I am trying to create a function decorator which passes a Playwright `Page`(`playwright.sync_api._generated.Page)` object to the wrapped function.

**Issue**: For most function calls, I would be able to return the value returned by the function call. However, since Playwright necessitates the `browser.close()` call, I can't simply return the `Page` object. I am not sure whether the problem is in (1) the function decorator which I have defined, or (2) my usage of the function decorator.

I tried to model my decorator after `pytest` fixtures. Using `pytest`, I would do something like this:

```py
@pytest.fixture(scope="module")
def playwright_page():
    with sync_playwright() as play:
        browser = play.chromium.launch()
        page = browser.new_page()
        yield page
        browser.close()
```

and then

```py
def open_google(playwright_page):
    playwright_page.goto("https://google.com")
```

---

**Function Decotator**:

```py
>>> from playwright.sync_api import sync_playwright
>>> def playwright_page(func):
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            with sync_playwright() as play:
                browser = play.chromium.launch()
                page = browser.new_page()
                yield page
                browser.close()
        return wrapper
```

**Attempt 1**:

```py
>>> @playwright_page
def open_google():
    page.goto("https://google.com")

    
>>> open_google()
<generator object playwright_page.<locals>.wrapper at 0x0000015C5F6CBC10>
```

**Attempt 2**:

```py
>>> @playwright_page
    def open_google():
        page = next(page)
        page.goto("https://google.com")

    
>>> open_google()
<generator object playwright_page.<locals>.wrapper at 0x0000015C5FDB7F90>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of trying to yield the `Page` object, such as for `pytest` fixtures, I should have been calling `func` and passing the `Page` object.

```py
>>> from playwright.sync_api import sync_playwright
>>> def playwright_page(func):
        def wrapper():
            with sync_playwright() as play:
                browser = play.chromium.launch()
                page = browser.new_page()
                results = func(page)
                browser.close()
                return results
        return wrapper


>>> @playwright_page
    def open_google(page):
        page.goto("https://google.com")
```

Comment: I'd add that if the function's return value might matter, the decorator should probably do something like `results = func(page)` and then `return results` after `browser.close()`